# Using Qt Resource for icons in a dll

Tags: qt, dll, icons

I need to build a c++ dll with only one QT dialog which will have some icons. I added these icons in the Qt Creator/Qt Designer. I created a resource file and added these images to it. These icons appear in the Qt Designer, but at run time they do not show up.

There is no .pro file. So I can not add `RESOURCES += myRes.qrc` as suggested on some similar topics. Also `Q_INIT_RESOURCE(myRes);` can not be invoked.

Any ideas what to do here?

Comment: What do you mean by `can not be invoked`?

Comment: Just run your qrc file through the [RCC tool](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/rcc.html) and generate a source file that you can compile into your DLL? Or am I not following you exactly? What are you using, Designer or Creator? Or Visual Studio?

Comment: How are you accessing the icons at run time? Perhaps they are in your resource area but you're just not getting their address correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved..

I was using Visual Studio 2010 to code the dll and dialog was created in the QT Creator. Resource file was created using QT Creator as well.

> Solution was to add qrc file (generated using QT Creator) to the dll
>   project in the Visual Studio. No other modifications needed to be done.

No .pro file and no Q_INIT_RESOURCE(myRes) needed to be created/invoked.

Thanks for help :)